# How to add 'save format' button to ALV screen?

Tags: abap

I'm adding double ALV screens on the same form, it works pretty fine, but one of it lacks of necessary button.

```
CALL METHOD gr_alv->set_table_for_first_display
        EXPORTING
          i_save               = 'A'
          i_default            = 'X'
          is_layout            = ls_layout
          it_toolbar_excluding = lt_exclude
        CHANGING
          it_outtab            = gt_aufk[]
          it_fieldcatalog      = lv_fieldcat
          it_filter            = lt_filter
        EXCEPTIONS
          OTHERS               = 1.
```

Where should i look at?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean "save variant"?

Comment: more like 'save layout'. I've marked 'change layout' button on screenshot, there should be one to save changes.

Comment: sorry, mixed something up there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's in the documentation:](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/2b/c670f702cf11d3b497006094192fe3/content.htm)

> If you use parameter `I_SAVE`, passing a layout structure with
>   `IS_VARIANT` is a required step.

You need to tell the ALV the key data for the layouts (program name, and if you have multiple lists per program, an additional handle):

```
...
CALL METHOD gr_alv->set_table_for_first_display
    EXPORTING
      i_save     = 'A'    
      is_variant = VALUE disvariant( repid = sy-repid )
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.